# AppConfig.get_model usage in custom manager

Tags: django, django-models

So i need to get model to use self.model in my Custom manager within [AppConfig.get_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model), but I don't understand how to use it.

<<managers.py>>

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
use_in_migrations = True
model = ???

def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_("email is required"))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('Superuser should to have flag is_superuser=True'))

    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? As long as you declare the manager as an attribute Django will internally set the model attribute on the manager.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Now I want to define model manually